# fuerte's supported python is 2.6 that's not supported on Precise

Tags: ros, python2.7, ubuntu, ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I noticed (while I'm looking at [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/59363/how-to-install-ros-fuerte-with-the-dependency-to-python-26-when-python-27-also-exists-in-ubuntu1204/)) that official python version in `fuerte` is 2.6 ([link to REP-003](http://ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html)), which is [no longer supported in Ubuntu Precise](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop) (there's a way to install 2.7 though). I'm just curious what was the decision made in this regard? Prioritize `Lucid` as a earlier stable distro? Is there a link to a discussion?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61099/fuerte%27s-supported-python-is-2.6-that%27s-not-supported-on-precise/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2013-04-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My interpretation of REP-0003 is that Python 2.6 is the *minimum* version supported by Fuerte. Probably, that entry should have explicitly stated "Python 2.6 and 2.7". Since Precise came out shortly after Fuerte was released, it's easy to understand how that might have been overlooked at the time.

All Fuerte Precise release testing was done with Python 2.7, so I doubt there are many serious problems due to the newer version, which is highly compatible with 2.6, anyway.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-04-20**:
Ah, release timing of `fuerte` and `Ubuntu` explains. I also found in the same `REP` that says "Our intent with Python is to track the minimum version provided in the supported Ubuntu platforms, " so I guess you're right.